# Class not found in eval()'d code in line 1

Tags: laravel-5

After I follow all the instructions for the installation of Zicaco/Entrust package I try to follow instructions to create roles and permissions but I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'App\models\Role' not found in eval()'d code on line 1
```

When I run the following command:

```
$owner = new App\models\Role();
```

When I run the same command again I get another error:

```
Cannot redeclare class App\Role
```

and it takes me out of the artisan tinker.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following for laravel 5.

```
$owner = new App\Role();
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this when trying to follow the Laracasts instruction on Eloquent101.  I found that the namespace is the problem.  My laravel application namespace is "dashboard" and the root directory is also "dashboard".  These do not need to be the same.  So I ran this as

```
$article = new dashboard\Article;
```

In the laracast presentation, they used

```
$article = new App\Article;
```

So, his namespace must have been "App" which is confusing because the top level directory is "app".